# How do I put a graphics driver into use?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I just installed the experimental (version 310) proprietary NVIDIA driver for *NVIDIA GeForce GTX 550Ti* card.

For some reason, the GUI did not come up, so I did it entirely through the terminal, using the `jockey-text` utility as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation_without_X_.2BAC8_from_the_console).

How can I put the driver into use? `jockey-text --list` outputs the following:

```
kmod:nvidia_experimental_310 - nvidia_experimental_310 (Proprietary, Enabled, Not in use)
```

I assume the 'enabled' part means the kernel module is enabled; how can I use it?

Comment: did you either restart X (log out and back in) or reboot ? What happens when you run `gksu nvidia-settings`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Rebooted several times. The X Server Configurator by NVIDIA comes up. I've used this before, and I saw it in the applications menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if jockey-text reports Not in use it doesn't mean that the driver is not in use.

To really determine if the nvidia driver is in use, run the following commands.

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

I you see nvidia then the nvidia driver is loaded. If not, you need load it.

Then run

```
nvidia-settings
```

It's a graphical utility that will not only let you know which version of the driver that you're running but also let you configure multi-monitor setup among other things.

[image]

From the command line, you can also run the following command to get the driver details.

```
modinfo nvidia_experimental_310
```

Comment: You got it! The driver is indeed in use, thank you very much for your help.